# Is it possible to establish case roles other than client and manager with webform-civicrm integration?

Tags: civicrm, webforms

So I have a case definition that besides the client and the case manager, also includes a navigator, referral and provider roles.  The webform works great for everything, including establishing the relationships for the other roles outside of the case (shows up in Other Relationships in the case view), however I can't see a way to flag those relationships as case roles, is this possible?  Perhaps it is even possible via Rules, which I started to look at, but I have not yet been able to figure out how to make it work.